# Could not get binary data in ASP.NET Core 3 from HTML/JS client through nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I have **HTML/JS client** side that communicate with **nodejs/express server** side. The client sends file to the node server - everything works fine so far.
The node server calls https.request to send the binary data to a**nother ASP.NET Core 3 component** (server).
The issue is that the ASP.NET Core 3.1 controller keep getting errors/empty data.
The API: TransferModel from the controller.cs either get empty data array or throws exceptions (depends ont the changes i am doing in the nodejs)

### Client/HTML Side

```html
<label style="font-weight: bold;">Upload Model File...</label>
    <form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>
      <br><input class="button" type="submit">
    </form>
```

### Node JS Sever - partial

```js
var express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const plantAPI = require('./plantSimAPI')
var formidable = require('formidable');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var serverUrl = 'localhost'
var port = '5000'

app.post('/fileupload', (req, res) => {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.onPart = function (part) {
    if (!part.filename) {
      // let formidable handle all non-file parts
      form.handlePart(part);
      return;
    }
    part.on('data', function (data) {
      transferModel(data);    
    });
    part.on('end', function () {
      transferModel([]);
      res.send(200);
    });
    part.on('error', function (err) {
      // handle this too
      res.json(err);
    });
  }

  form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    //pass the file to the plant sim server
    // plantSim.
      //res.send(200);
      console.log('ahmad');
  });
});


    function transferModel(data, ondone) {
        this.callPlantSimAPI2('/plantsim/api/model/transfer', 'PUT', data, () => {
            if (ondone) ondone();
        });

    }
    
    function callPlantSimAPI2(path, method, data, onDone) {
        const options = {
            host: serverUrl,
            port: port,
            path: path,
            method: method,
            agent: new https.Agent({
                rejectUnauthorized: false,
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" //"application/octet-stream"
            }
        };

        var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
            console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
            console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                console.log('BODY: ' + path + ' : ' + chunk);
                if (onDone) onDone(chunk);
            });
            res.on('error', (err) => {
                if (onDone) onDone("")
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                if (onDone) onDone("")
            })
        });

        req.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
            if (onDone) onDone("");
        });

        // write data to request body
        if(data && data.length>0) req.write(data);
        req.end();
    }
```

### ASP.NET Web API Core3.1

## Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            //first routing
            app.UseRouting();
            //then
            app.UseCors(
                options => options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()
            );
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

        }
```

## Controller.cs

```
namespace PlantSimAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("simapi")]
    [Route("plantsim/api")]
    public class PlantSimAPIController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPut]
        [Route("model/transfer")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TransferModel( [FromBody]byte[] data)
        {
             try
                {
                    //byte[] data = { };
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(1024*8))
                    {
                        await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(ms);
                        data = ms.ToArray();
                        //do something with my data
                    }
                    return Ok();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Log message
                    this._logger.LogError(ex.Message);
                    //return bad result
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search...and lot of issues during the solution, here is what I end up with:

1. Nodejs server:

remove:

`headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" //"application/octet-stream"
            }`

from the options

2. Multi Threading:

because of getting the data in chunks - this is how nodejs sends the data to the ASP.NET Core (or in general), I end up with exposing two APIs:

- nodejs piece:

```js
app.post('/fileupload', (req, res) => {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.multiples = false;
  var ind = 0;
  form.onPart = function (part) {
    if (!part.filename) {
      // let formidable handle all non-file parts
      form.handlePart(part);
      return;
    }
    part.on('data', function (data) {
      plantSim.transferModel(data, ind++);
    });
    part.on('end', function () {
      plantSim.transferModelCompleted([], ind);
      res.send(200);
    });
    part.on('error', function (err) {
      // handle this too
      res.json(err);
    });
  }
```

Note that we have first API to transfer data with the data chunk and it's index.

Then we have another data that transfer nothing but the total number of chunks.

- .NET Core API: one API to get data with index of the chunk, another API is with total number of chunks.

When getting the data (transfert (data, index)) we put the data in Dictionary and when getting the transferComplete(count) call, we save the number of chunks.

since everything is async, after transfer and transferComplete we check whether Dictoinary length == number of chunks, and only then we sort the Dictionary and save the file in the disk.